# Resize existing image based on parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I noticed the following on a php website:

[image]

this image has the url `https://ecovolis.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/12939644_1093683970674287_858103448_n.jpg`;

however when you add a parameter `?w=200` to the url, the image returned gets automatically resized (reduced) to the width 200px.

I know this was made in php since it's a wordpress site, but how I can't figure out how they did it.

Can you please explain that to me together with an actual example in php?

Thank you in advance. :)

PS: I'd like to know the functionality behind this in php.

Comment: What parts do you think are needed for this to work? For starters you'll need some way for the .jpg to be linked to a php script and not just the static image using mod_rewrite or similar. There are probably enough resources someone else will point to, I just want to warn you that you should limit which sizes are accepted and only cache those sizes to prevent someone spamming your hard drive and/or cpu.

Answer (score 0):

there are similar talks as follows:
[PHP resize from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473241/php-resize-from-url)

In that page some hints:

Huh, it seems that imagecreatefromjpeg accepts as a parameter url, take a look http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

getimagesize works with URL too, suport was added in php 4.0.5 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php